# What is the general approach of rotating an object towards another object?

Tags: algorithm, user-interface, language-agnostic

In a 2D plane, I have 2 objects (A and B) with 2 coordinates. Their centers are A(xA, yA) and B(xB, yB) (and C(xC, yC)=C(xB, yA) as AC parallel to the OX line and BC is perpendicular on AC). I can manipulate the rotation of an object and I have access to all usual math operations and can use degrees and radians.

I researched but I couldn't find anything explained in detail.

I also tried using the math formula with arccos formula as follows:

I tried to calculate the distance from A to B (AB) using the Pythagoras theorem, then calculate A to C (AC), then calculate cos(angle)=AC/AB, so the final angle to which I would need to rotate object A towards B is arccos(AC/AB).

Problem is this sounds insanely buggy as you can probably get a lot of digits and ruin everything.

So how can I do this? Please explain mathematically. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what problem you're having is a little unclear. If you're not sure what the correct formula to use is, then this sounds more like an issue with understanding the underlying math for solving your problem than a programming question. Maybe it belongs instead on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not really clear what you are trying to do. Maybe you should add one or two pictures how the objects look, and how they are oriented w.r.t. each other before and after.

Comment: What do you mean by "rotate towards"? Are you talking about something like [billboarding](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/billboarding/), but in 2D?

Comment: A picture would speak 1000 words here.

Comment: I tried to explain as well as I could.

The answer given by Abion47 was fulfilling, if that makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to find the angle between two points is to take their arctangent (a.k.a. inverse tangent). You were on the right track with using cosine, but tangent simplifies the process by not requiring the distance between the points to be known.

As such, you'll want to use an atan2 function in your choice of language. The C# [Math.Atan2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2(v=vs.110).aspx), for example:

```
double angle = Math.Atan2(B.Y - A.Y, B.X - A.X);
```

Note: This particular function returns the angle in radians.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to rotate object A towards B with C like center of the rotation ?

If it's the case you have only to rotate with an angle of 90 degrees because your triangle is special. But if you want to apply a rotation with a specific angle around a specific center you have to use a transformation TRT.

You will find more explanation [here](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/affine/aroundPoint/).

Comment: no, so, supposing A is facing C, I want A to face B